# com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot deserialize object with new readObject()/writeObject() methods in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, xstream

I am developing **Spring Boot + Batch** example where reading customer data from the customer.csv file. While reading the data I am getting below error. It looks like I need to `unmarshall` the Customer using `Xstream` convert.

```
org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: XStream unmarshalling exception; nested exception is com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot deserialize object with new readObject()/writeObject() methods
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Cannot deserialize object with new readObject()/writeObject() methods
class               : java.time.LocalDateTime
required-type       : java.time.LocalDateTime
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializableConverter
path                : /customer/birthdate
line number         : 7
class[1]            : com.example.domain.Customer
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
version             : 5.1.3.RELEASE
-------------------------------
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.convertXStreamException(XStreamMarshaller.java:851) ~[spring-oxm-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.doUnmarshal(XStreamMarshaller.java:829) ~[spring-oxm-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.unmarshalXmlStreamReader(XStreamMarshaller.java:786) ~[spring-oxm-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.unmarshalXmlEventReader(XStreamMarshaller.java:777) ~[spring-oxm-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.support.AbstractMarshaller.unmarshalStaxSource(AbstractMarshaller.java:411) ~[spring-oxm-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.support.AbstractMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractMarshaller.java:354) ~[spring-oxm-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.doRead(StaxEventItemReader.java:243) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:92) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:94) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:161) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:119) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:113) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:203) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:399) [spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:313) [spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144) [spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137) [spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) [spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:214) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:186) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:172) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:166) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.ReadingXmlApplication.main(ReadingXmlApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot deserialize object with new readObject()/writeObject() methods
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Cannot deserialize object with new readObject()/writeObject() methods
class               : java.time.LocalDateTime
required-type       : java.time.LocalDateTime
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializableConverter
path                : /customer/birthdate
line number         : 7
class[1]            : com.example.domain.Customer
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
version             : 5.1.3.RELEASE
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializableConverter.doUnmarshal(SerializableConverter.java:318) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:503) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:429) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1230) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.doUnmarshal(XStreamMarshaller.java:826) ~[spring-oxm-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
```

Customer.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class Customer {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDateTime birthdate;
}
```

customer.xml

```
<customers>
    <customer>
        <id>1</id>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>Doe</lastName>
        <birthdate>10-10-1988 19:43:23</birthdate>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <id>2</id>
        <firstName>James</firstName>
        <lastName>Moss</lastName>
        <birthdate>01-04-1991 10:20:23</birthdate>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <id>3</id>
        <firstName>Jonie</firstName>
        <lastName>Gamble</lastName>
        <birthdate>21-07-1982 11:12:13</birthdate>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <id>4</id>
        <firstName>Mary</firstName>
        <lastName>Kline</lastName>
        <birthdate>07-08-1973 11:27:42</birthdate>
    </customer>
```

**JobConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public StaxEventItemReader<Customer> customerItemReader(){
        Map<String, Class> aliases = new HashMap<>();
        aliases.put("customer", Customer.class);

        XStreamMarshaller ummarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        ummarshaller.setAliases(aliases);

        StaxEventItemReader<Customer> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/data/customer.xml"));
        reader.setFragmentRootElementName("customer");
        reader.setUnmarshaller(ummarshaller);

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Customer> customerItemWriter(){
        return items -> {
            for (Customer customer : items) {
                System.out.println(customer.toString());
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Customer, Customer>chunk(10)
                .reader(customerItemReader())
                .writer(customerItemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue using following way -

**CustomerConverter.java**

```
public class CustomerConverter implements Converter {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter DT_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return type.equals(Customer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        // Don't do anything
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        reader.moveDown();
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setId(Long.valueOf(reader.getValue()));

        reader.moveUp();
        reader.moveDown();
        customer.setFirstName(reader.getValue());

        reader.moveUp();
        reader.moveDown();
        customer.setLastName(reader.getValue());

        reader.moveUp();
        reader.moveDown();
        customer.setBirthdate(LocalDateTime.parse(reader.getValue(), DT_FORMATTER));

        return customer;
    }
}
```

Here is the change

```
@Bean
    public StaxEventItemReader<Customer> customerItemReader(){
        Map<String, Class> aliases = new HashMap<>();
        aliases.put("customer", Customer.class);

        CustomerConverter converter = new CustomerConverter();

        XStreamMarshaller ummarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        ummarshaller.setAliases(aliases);
        ummarshaller.setConverters(converter);

        StaxEventItemReader<Customer> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/data/customer.xml"));
        reader.setFragmentRootElementName("customer");
        reader.setUnmarshaller(ummarshaller);

        return reader;
    }
```